# Elasticsearch nested aggregation out of memory even only 5 documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm aggregating tweet text field for 5 doc only and get out of memory error.

The tweet text field is a nested field in my data model, analyzed. The index is 150Gb and the tweet text field is very large in total. However, I'm using a query to match only 5 documents.

I see some other stack over page says Elasticsearch load all the data for the field to do the aggregation. Is it still true now?

The query I use returns only 5 documents, it is a filter on another nested field.

The aggregation is like this:

```
"aggs": {
            "nestedAgg": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "t_tweets"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "tweetTermsAgg": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "t_tweets.text",
                            "size": 200,
                            "exclude": ["t.co", "https", "rt", "to", "a", "for", "of", "in", "http", "and", "is", "on", "your", "you", "via", "with", "how", "by", "at", "this", "are", "from", "i", "that", "be", "about", "what", "about", "can", "more", "my", "have", "an", "out", "our", "will", "we", "why", "do", "get", "up", "as", "just", "if", "or", "so", "the", "has", "it's", "need", "but", "great", "w", "best", "its", "no", "when", "not", "been", "than", "there", "was", "some", "don't", "most", "these", "."]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The mapping for the tweet nested object is

```
"t_tweets": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "created_utc": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "hashtags": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "double",
            "doc_values": false
          },
          "keep_forever": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "doc_values": false
          },
          "language": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "doc_values": false
          },
          "mentions": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
```

Anything wrong with my aggregation? Or is there anyway I can get this over?

Comment: If `t_tweets.text` is analyzed text field then I am not surprised it's running out of memory. It's creating a lot of buckets and those need memory. It doesn't matter how many documents there are. If each document has 500 00 terms in it in that field, it should be enough to get you into trouble.

Comment: There are actually not a lot of data in the 5 docs. Each doc is for one twitter user. We save 30 days tweets, and only the tweets matches our keywords.
I did another try to move the documents out of the big index and build a small index(400mb). Aggregate on the small index is super fast even on many more number of documents(10K docs). 

Does that make sense?

Comment: If you decrease the size of the index, it will decreease the number of documents per shard, and so yes it makes the search faster then.

Comment: The search itself is pretty fast. I can get the 5 doc in sub second. But if I add the aggregation in the request, it is running forever and cpu/ram increase dramatically.